# For Each GridviewRow Loop, with where clause?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, for-loop

Is there any easier way of using the code:

```
For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In gvGridviewExample.Rows
    If gvRow.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        'Do Something
    End If
Next
```

Such as when using a iEnumerable you theoritically (psuedo code style) add a:

```
gvGridviewExample.Where(Function(chR) chR.Row = DataRow)
```

I just wondered if there is an easier way of coding this out?

Thanks,

Firstcape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your first snippet actually *is* very simple and clear, the `Rows` property of a `GridView` returns **only `DataRows`**. So you don't need to check the type at all.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rows.aspx)

> The `Rows` property (collection) is used to store the data rows in a
>   GridView control.
>
> Only rows with their RowType property set to
>   `DataControlRowType.DataRow` are stored in the Rows collection. The
>   GridViewRow objects that represent the header, footer, and pager rows
>   are not included in the collection.

You can only have different types in events like `RowCreated` or `RowDataBound`. If you want to access the header, footer or pager outside of these events you can use the appropriate properties of the `GridView` like `HeaderRow` or `FooterRow`.

Comment: I understand it is very simple and clear, I was wondering if there was anything else that helped, but as you pointed out it only collects datarows.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tim's answer, which is 100% correct for your specific case, you can use [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) in similar situations, i.e. when you only want to iterate over all visible rows:

```
gvGridViewExample.Rows
    .Where(Function(r) r.Displayed = True)  ' Apply filter
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(Function(x) x.DoSomething())  ' Do something...
```

or

```
For Each row in gvGridViewExample.Rows.Where(Function(r) r.Displayed = True)
    row.DoSomething()
Next
```

Comment: The `Where` is redundant(that's the whole point of my answer) since `GridView.Rows` returns only rows with `DataControlRowType.DataRow`. The `ForEach` wouldn't compile since it's a method in `List(Of T)` but the `Where` returns an `IEnumerable(Of T)`. You would need a `ToList` before. But that's wasting memory since a simple `foreach` works perfectly.

Comment: In this case, you are right, that's why you got my upvote. I just wanted to add this possibility, to address cases where the `RowType` is not the criteria inside `If ... Then` statement.
You've edited your comment, and I've already updated my answer ;-)

Comment: To make it compile you also have to cast the `Rows` property to an `IEnumerable(Of GridViewRow)` with `gvGridViewExample.Rows.Cast(Of GridViewRow)()`.  I don't want to nitpick, but you see the effort to be able to do something that is useless anyway ;)

Comment: But the [`DataGridViewRowsCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.aspx) already implements `IEnumerable<T>`, doesn't it?!

Comment: No, it implements `IEnumerable`. That's the reason why you need the cast and why you also need to specify the type in a `foreach`. So the row in the following foreach is of type `Object` not `GridViewRow`: `For Each row In GridView1.Rows  Next` You have to spiecify the type for an implicit cast: `For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Next`